# alert message not popping up

Tags: sharepoint-designer, jquery, csom

```
 var j = jQuery.noConflict(); 
 function PreSaveAction() { 
 var txtTitle = j.(":input[title='Application Name']").val(); 
   alert(txtTitle);
   if(txtTitle == ''){        
   alert("Value Cannot be Blank");          
   return false;
}
else{
   return true;
    }  
}
```

Comment: i used presave function reference from google but somehow alert  popup is not coming

Comment: Why do you have ":" before input?

Comment: in google reference, it was given. actually i m new to this so dnt have xct idea abt everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove "." from  your code at line number 3 i.e `j(":input[title='Application Name']").val();`

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict(); 
 function PreSaveAction() { 
 var txtTitle = j(":input[title='Application Name']").val(); 
   alert(txtTitle);
   if(txtTitle == ''){        
   alert("Value Cannot be Blank");          
   return false;
}
else{
   return true;
    }  
}
```

Comment: i tried removing '.' too but after removing 'j' gets some hyperlink which on click gives message ' code hyperlink not found'

Comment: You tried giving id to the input field and using it as the selector in the script ?

Comment: I am working on SHarepoint designer newform.aspx advance mode , so need of giving Id/selector separtely

Comment: then try removing ":" this from  `j(":input[title='Application Name']").val();` i.e  `j("input[title='Application Name']").val();`

Comment: did that too, no change

Comment: This is the lame question but i should ask. Are you using this after jquery.js script ?

Comment: obviously i m using jquery,js library.

Comment: anyways its sorted, i got it from ID of textbox in Sharepoint list using DOM explorer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function PreSaveAction(){
        var txtTitle = $("input[title='Application Name']").val();
        alert(txtTitle);
        // ...
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, ites working for me

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var j = jQuery.noConflict(); 
function PreSaveAction() {
 var txtTitle = j("input[title='Application Name']").val(); 
   alert(txtTitle);
   if(txtTitle == ''){        
   alert("Value Cannot be Blank");          
   return false;
}
else{
   return true;
    }  
}
</script>
```

Use `j("input[title='Application Name']").val()` instead of j.`("input[title='Application Name']").val()`

Your '.' makes the issue.

Comment: i tried ur code also but its not working for me... i am currently working on sharepoint designer and newform.aspx in advanced mode

Comment: Made a change in code. try that now. Remove '.' wherever you use 'j'

Comment: see above comment